# xmppStreamDidConnect never gets called in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xmppframework

I am trying to connect to my chat server in a Swift app using XMPPFramework, but the didConnect delegate method never gets called.
I have created a basic app in Objective C and I can connect and authenticate in my chat sever without problems.

In the Swift project I tried to connect with the code:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var stream:XMPPStream = XMPPStream()
    var reconnect:XMPPReconnect = XMPPReconnect()
    var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    stream.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
    stream.myJID = XMPPJID(string: "user@chatserver.net")
    reconnect.activate(stream)
    do {
        try stream.connect(withTimeout: XMPPStreamTimeoutNone)
    }
    catch let err{
        print("error occured in connecting\(String(describing: err.localizedDescription))")
    }
    return true
}
```

I’ve debugged XMPPFramework and in the method - `(void)handleStreamFeatures`  a call to the delegate is executed :

`[multicastDelegate xmppStreamDidConnect:self];`

I’ve watched the multicastDelegateObject and has a node with reference to my delegate, and to OS_dispatch_queue_main, but after execution my `xmppStreamDidConnect` method isn’t executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is described in this [Github Issue,](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/issues/1126) the problem was the method declaration.
My `xmppStreamDidConnect` need an underscore, the root problem was that if you don't import the swift extensions the compiler marks that declaration as incorrect, although it works.
So to fix my problem, I need to import the pod 'XMPPFramework/Swift' and change the method declaration to

```
func xmppStreamDidConnect(_ sender: XMPPStream) {
```